# Check if a string exists in whole firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an android app and I want to check if a string (like the following userCPF and userCRM) exists in order to avoid duplicate values. I´ve been investigating but it looks that all I can add is listeners, when I just want to check if an ID exists or not already.

**Question**

How can I do this?

Following are my ProfileActivity.java and UserInformation (database format) class.

First, ProfileActivity:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private TextView textView;
private Button buttonLogout;

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

private EditText editTextFName, editTextLName, editTextEmail, editTextCPF, editTextCRM;
private Spinner spinnerState;
private Button buttonSave;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //if user is not logged in
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    //initializing views
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    editTextFName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFName);
    editTextLName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLName);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextCPF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCPF);
    editTextCRM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCRM);
    spinnerState = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerState);
    buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
    buttonLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);

    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    textView.setText("Bem Vindo(a) Dr. " + user.getEmail());

    editTextEmail.setText(user.getEmail());

    //adding listener to buttons
    buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void saveUserInformation() {
    String firstName = editTextFName.getText().toString().trim();
    String lastName = editTextLName.getText().toString().trim();
    String userEmail = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
    String userCPF = editTextCPF.getText().toString().trim();
    String userCRM = editTextCRM.getText().toString().trim();
    String crmState = spinnerState.getSelectedItem().toString();

    //checking if email and passwords are empty
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(firstName)){
        editTextFName.setError("Por favor, digite seu primeiro nome");
        editTextFName.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(lastName)){
        editTextLName.setError("Por favor, digite seu sobrenome");
        editTextLName.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail)){
        editTextEmail.setError("Por favor, digite seu e-mail");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userCPF)){
        editTextCPF.setError("Por favor, digite seu CPF");
        editTextCPF.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userCRM)){
        editTextCRM.setError("Por favor, digite seu CRM");
        editTextCRM.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation(firstName, lastName, userEmail, userCPF, crmState, userCRM);


    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userInformation);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Dados Salvos...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, BadgeActivity.class));

}




@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //if logout button is pressed
    if (view == buttonLogout) {
        mAuth.signOut();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    if (view == buttonSave) {

        saveUserInformation();
    }
}
```

Then, UserInformation

```
public class UserInformation {

public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public String userEmail;
public String crmState;
public String userCRM;
public String userCPF;

public UserInformation(){

}

public UserInformation(String firstName, String lastName, String userEmail, String userCPF, String crmState, String userCRM) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.crmState = crmState;
    this.userCRM = userCRM;
    this.userCPF = userCPF;
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserInformation");
 ref.orderByChild("userCRM").equalTo(CRM_value_here).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
 if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
    Toast.makeText(Activity_Name.this, "Stop!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return;
 }
}
   @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
 });
```

Can do the above, or if you are using the id of the user as key then can do this:

```
FirebaseUser currentuser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

ref.orderByKey().equalTo(currentuser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){

 //like above

   }
```

Comment: My issue is that I need to check whether the user CPF or userCRM has already been entered under ANY other userUid in the folder. Unfortunately the structure you helped me with hasnt worked yet.

Comment: Yes! I had to study a little bit in order to better understand haha