# Check for a url in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a URL to firebase database under "favourites" but if its not already there. How to check it. I am just a beginner. Here what I have tried for now.

[image: database]

```
  databaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");              
  firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            databaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).orderByChild("favourites").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        if (d.child("img_url").equals(uploadcurrent.getImageUrl()))
                        Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Already added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        else {
                            String key=databaseReference.push().getKey();
                            databaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("favourites").child(key).child("img_url").setValue(uploadcurrent.getImageUrl());

                            //do something if not exists

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }


            });

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973025/check-if-a-string-exists-in-whole-firebase-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the existens of an url directly in the query. For that, please change the following lines of code:

```
databaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");              
firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
databaseReference
    .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
    .orderByChild("favourites")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

to

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference favouritesRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid).child("favourites");
Query query = favouritesRef.orderByChild("img_url").equalTo(url):
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

In which the `url` is the String representation of the url that you are actually looking for.

Comment: you should probably also add the query's listener for completeness.

Comment: @samthecodingman Added the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` also to the solution.

Comment: Just simply adding that line doesn't help, it needs the function body as well. The way you've written it suggests the listener code from the question will work without modification. A simple `hasChildren()` should suffice.

Comment: /* ... */ please complete it. i want toast if the url already exists